# What to do when moderators are guessing the answer instead of closing it?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682528/regex-no-success-with-six-number-start-with-5000#22682575) question few minutes back. The question is not at all clear and as far as what I have read in the FAQ and heard about the functioning of this site. Questions like these should be closed as "Unclear what OP is asking"

But I found that the Moderators are also answering. I am not saying anything about there potential but dont you think that it is aganist the rule. I respectfully respect all the moderators here. But just curious to know that what is right and correct?

<sub>I am really sorry if I am asking for a big trouble by asking this question here. I have no intention to blame or put a finger on any moderator.</sub>

Comment: Moderators are human too, so they can make mistakes. I don't think there are strict rules forbidding moderators to answer bad questions.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe:- Yes I fuly agree and as I said I am not against anyone. I am just saying when you know or when it is pointed then is it hard to close the question? instead of changing the entire content which is  done now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682528/regex-4-6-digits-ending-with-00-but-lowest-value-is-5000

Comment: *What* about a diamond next to your name, prevents you from making the judgment calls that every 3k+ user makes on a regular basis?

Comment: It was unclear but after editing it looks fine to me (editing feature is in place to to improve posts after all). In the current state of this question, answers become relevant. For some users it is hard to explain the issue properly and as a community we should help them in articulating the problem better instead of a quick close vote.

Comment: @michaelb958:- This question is not a duplicate of that one. I respectfully ask you to please read both the question and the context.

Comment: @user3414693 Same topic, same rant, same answer; therefore duplicate.

Comment: This is (and is not) a duplicate. In the general sense the broad strokes are answered by the other question. What makes this 'not a duplicate' is that this user has a specific usecase that differs from the other question (I'll go into detail in my answer below). I'm re-opening to answer his *specific* question and cover ground not covered in the other answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not going to 'get in trouble' for bringing up *any* moderator action. In fact, *we welcome it*.

The moderator in question decided to do two things:

- Edit the question to be more clear
- Answer the edited question

I wish every 3K user did that.

In this case, the question could have been closed as 'unclear what you're asking', *or* if the moderator (and by extension, any 2K user) could see if they understood enough of the question to edit it to be answerable.

Both approaches are valid.

The latter approach even has the benefit that if you edit the question into shape  *and* answer it, you get reputation (Shiny).

As moderators, we don't always have the time to edit a question into shape, but when we have the time, we try to.

In this specific case, the question wasn't really unclear (meaning what they wanted was ambiguous as written), it just needed some more examples and some grammatical cleanup.

Comment: Thats a perfect explanation to my question. Thanks a lot! I highly appreciate this `In this case, the question could have been closed as 'unclear what you're asking', or if the moderator (and by extension, any 2K user) could see if they understood enough of the question to edit it to be answerable.` Good work MODERATORS. Once again thanks! +1

Comment: @user3414693 I think it is worth emphasizing that any user with full edit privileges (2k and above) could have done this.  The moderator in question didn't use any special moderator powers to do this.